# Deleting N first chars from string

Tags: c++, string, character

I want to delete the first 10 chars from a string in C++. How can I do that?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Like this:

```
str.erase(0,10);
```

...

Comment: ugh yes that works. I tried str.erase(str.begin(), str.end()+10);
which gave me an crash aswell before <.<
Thanks!

Comment: str.begin(), str.begin() + 10

Comment: Faster than str=str.substr(10) as 8:11 on large strings.

Answer (score 9):

Use `std::string::substr`:

```
try {
   str = str.substr(10);
} catch (std::out_of_range&) {
     //oops str is too short!!!
}
```

1. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Comment: Thanks this one works aswell without a crash, the second one however is a little shorter.

Comment: @Paul it is indeed shorter while writing - but I must say that str.erase(size_t,size_t) has better performance in your case.

Comment: Good to know, my whole application is quite time intensive.

Comment: I meant the Michael's version is better in performance. Select his. (it is hard to be honest :-( )

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that there is more code here that you are not showing, and the problem is likely there.

This code works just fine:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string imgURL = "<img src=\"http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/sky.png";

    string str = imgURL;
    int urlLength = imgURL.length();
    urlLength = urlLength-10;
    str.erase (str.begin(), str.end()-urlLength);
    imgURL = str;

    cout << imgURL << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

With that said, there are shorter ways to do this, as others have mentioned.